# To sort an array in required manner

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

I need to sort the elements in the odd positions in the descending order and elements in the even position in ascending order. Here is my code, I'm unable to break the first loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, t;

    printf("Enter the size of the array\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int i, a[n];

    if ((n > 20) || (n <= 0))
        printf("Invalid Size");
    else
    {
        printf("Enter the values\n");
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < n; i + 2)
        {
            if (a[i] > a[i + 2])
            {
                t = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i + 2];
                a[i + 2] = t;
            }
        }
        for (i = 1; i < n; i + 2)
        {
            if (a[i] < a[i + 2])
            {
                t = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i + 2];
                a[i + 2] = t;
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            printf("%d\n", a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `;i+2` --> `;i += 2` ? And beware of out-of-bounds error.

Comment: In the declaration `int i, a[n];`, `n` is not constant so i'm not sure how this even compiled...

Comment: @JustinJ.: VLAs are standard. This is C, not C++.

Comment: As, I declared n and assigned a value to it by scanning before I declare array, I guess I can do that.

Comment: No checking for errors, `n` not initialised -> broken code.

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < n; i + 2)` -> `for (i = 0; i < n-2; i += 2)` to avoid access outside the array, i.e. use `i < n-2;`

Comment: You don't really do a sort. Your code just swaps two elements at the time. To sort the array, you need to compare with all other elements. Anyway, try this - 1) split the array into two arrays, 2) use qsort on each array, 3) reconstruct the full array. In this way you don't need to write the sort code yourself

Comment: `int n, t;` -> `int n=0, t;`

Comment: @Olaf : OK.  But I tried in VS2015 and get errors: `main.c : expression must have a constant value` and `main.c : 'a': unknown size` + 2 more on that line.  Is Visual Studio non standard?

Comment: @JustinJ.: Well, if you will use an archaic C90-only compiler, then you run into problems using merely ancient features.  VLAs have been a part of Standard C since the end of the last millennium (C99).  The fact that Microsoft hasn't woken up to the new millennium is a separate problem.

Answer (score 2):

For starters according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

There is no great sense to declare the variable `n` as having the type `int` that after that to check whether its value is less than zero.  It is much better to declare it as having the type `size_t`.

And the array should be declared after the check

```
if ((n > 20) || (n <= 0))
    printf("Invalid Size");
else
{
    int a[n];
    //...
```

In loops like this

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i + 2)
```

the variable `i`  is not increased. It is obvious that you mean `i += 2`.

And the loops only moves the first minimum even and the first maximum odd elements to the end of the array. You need additional loops that will do the same operation for other elements of the array. That is the implementation of the bubble sort algorithm is incorrect.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the array can be sorted according to the requirements for even and odd elements of the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N   20

int main(void) 
{
    int a[N] = { 18, 1, 16, 3, 14, 5, 12, 7, 10, 9, 8, 11, 6, 13, 4, 15, 2, 17, 0, 19 };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( size_t n = N, last; !( n < 3 ); n = last )
    {
        for ( size_t i = last = 2; i < n; i++ )
        {
            if ( ( i % 2 == 0 && a[i] < a[i - 2] ) ||
                 ( i % 2 == 1 && a[i - 2] < a[i] ) )
            {
                int tmp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i - 2];
                a[i - 2] = tmp;
                last = i;
            }
        }
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
18 1 16 3 14 5 12 7 10 9 8 11 6 13 4 15 2 17 0 19 
0 19 2 17 4 15 6 13 8 11 10 9 12 7 14 5 16 3 18 1
```

Answer (score 1):

- The most obvious problem is that your `for` never ends because `i` is never actually updated. The `i+2`  in `for (i = 0; i < n; i + 2)` does not update `i` which keeps its initia value forever.
  Try something like `for (i = 0; i < n; i=i+2)` instead.
- A second problem is that you are not really performing a sorting.
  I guess that you are trying to implement some sort of [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).
  It sorts using comparison. It is impossible to sort an array using less than `n logn` operation (when sorting using comparison). You are sorting the array in linear time and this should look as a red flag to you.

Try adding another `for`  as follows:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i+= 2)
    for (j = i+2; j < n; j+= 2)
        if (a[i] > a[j])
        {
            t = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = t;
        }
```

and most importantly then read about why you need it.

And if you feel brave you can swap the intgers without using an intermediate variable `t` as follows (read more on the topic here: [XOR swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm)):

```
if (a[i] > a[j])
{
    a[i] = a[i]^a[j];
    a[j] = a[j]^a[i];
    a[i] = a[i]^a[j];
}
```

Hope it helps.